# Container doesn't grow with (kwicks plugin) content

Tags: jquery, html, css, kwicks

I'm having an issue on the bottom of http://xweasel.chris-cole.de/v3/index.php with a container that doesn't fully grow in height with its content.

The cause seems to be a list, formatted by a plugin named kwicks.
It seems as if the list is floating and the floating is not cleared, or as if list is positioned absolute, but it's relative.

```
<div class="full-wrapper">
  <div class="inner-wrapper" style="background: #0f0;">

    <section>
      <div class="message numbers">
        <h2>xWeasel in numbers</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class='kwicks kwicks-horizontal kwicks-processed'>
        <li>
        </li>...    
      </ul>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```

`.inner-wrapper` grows with `.message.numbers` but not with `.kwicks`.

```
.kwicks{
  display:block;
  list-style-type:none;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}
.kwicks>*{
  display:block;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}
.kwicks.kwicks-processed>*{
  margin:0;
  position:absolute
}
.kwicks-horizontal>*{
  float:left
}
.kwicks-horizontal>:first-child{
  margin-left:0
}
.kwicks-vertical>:first-child{
  margin-top:0
}
```

Comment: the `ul` element has `height` zero... Maybe you could set a height to it... Like 100px.

Comment: Oh boy, why didn't I think of that? Works great now. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

This is the `ul` element which doesn't "grow" with its content.

Try to set a `height` on it... Like 100px.
;)